# MySQL query to mongoose query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying my best to learn MongoDB, how ever I'm stuck on a more difficult query. How to convert this query to a mongoose query?

```
 var week = function() {
    if (req.query.week == null || req.query.week < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return req.query.week;
    }
};
var sql = "SELECT rep, SUM(binder) as binder, WEEKDAY(sold_date) + 1 as day FROM sales  WHERE WEEK(sold_date, 1) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE, 1) - " + week() + " AND role = \"Sales\" GROUP BY rep, day";
```

Returns

```
{"rep":"Andy","binder":2600,"day":1},{"rep":"Andy","binder":2884,"day":2},{"rep":"Andy","binder":1055.5,"day":3},{"rep":"Andy","binder":2608,"day":5},{"rep":"Andy","binder":3500,"day":6},{"rep":"Benjamin","binder":1530,"day":1},{"rep":"Benjamin","binder":1158,"day":2},{"rep":"Benjamin","binder":1150,"day":3},{"rep":"Benjamin","binder":5188,"day":5},{"rep":"Benjamin","binder":2279.38,"day":6},{"rep":"Dane","binder":709,"day":5},{"rep":"Dane","binder":750,"day":6},{"rep":"David","binder":3100,"day":1},{"rep":"David","binder":500,"day":2},{"rep":"David","binder":600,"day":5},{"rep":"David","binder":1670,"day":6},{"rep":"Frank","binder":950,"day":2},{"rep":"Greg D","binder":5536,"day":2},{"rep":"Greg D","binder":1743.5,"day":3},{"rep":"Greg D","binder":1000,"day":6},{"rep":"Jack","binder":1700,"day":3},{"rep":"Jack","binder":1000,"day":5},{"rep":"Jack","binder":2050,"day":6},{"rep":"jacob","binder":200,"day":1},{"rep":"jacob","binder":850,"day":5},{"rep":"James","binder":1343,"day":1},{"rep":"James","binder":450,"day":2},{"rep":"James","binder":400,"day":6},{"rep":"Jordan","binder":1400,"day":3},{"rep":"Jordan","binder":400,"day":5},{"rep":"Mike Allen","binder":271,"day":2}
```

MongoDB table example

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("613d2d556de53fdd1ac90fe2"),
        "name" : {
                "first" : "Test",
                "last" : "Mctester"
        },
        "lead_src" : "website",
        "rep" : "Test",
        "binder" : 564,
        "job_number" : 5725389798798,
        "date_sold" : ISODate("2021-09-11T00:00:00Z"),
        "state" : "AL",
        "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2021-09-11T22:27:33.882Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i may have figured out the proper syntax

```
    deal.aggregate( [
   {
     $group: {
        _id: {
           rep: "$rep",
           ord_date: { $dayOfWeek: {
              date: "$date_sold"
           }}
        },
        total: { $sum: "$binder" }
     }
   }], (err, res) => {
     if (err) throw err
     console.log(res)
   }
 )
```